# Why am I receiving an exception on my server when creating a TIFF?

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008, tiff, encoder, pixelformat

I only receive an exception on my Windows Server Datacenter 2007 SP 2 server, not on my local Windows 7 PC.

I have wrapped the problematic call in a `try-catch-finally`, so that the rest of the program may execute normally.

How do I resolve the exception and generate the TIFF correctly on the server?

Exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException:
A generic error occurred in GDI+. at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String
filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams) at
TSEmails.TaskScheduleSlippage.CreateTIFFImageReport(DataTable
dataOfManyProjects, String fileName) in
D:\TSEmail\TSEmails\TaskScheduleSlippage.cs:line 236 at
TSEmails.TaskScheduleSlippage.GenerateOrganizationalEmail(DataTable
dataOfManyProjects, DataTable emailSettings) in
D:\TSEmail\TSEmails\TaskScheduleSlippage.cs:line 92
```

Line of code throwing the exception:

```
tiffImage.Save(fileName, info, encoderparams);
```

Relevant code:

```
private static void CreateTIFFImageReport(DataTable dataOfManyProjects, string fileName)
{//Line:210
    ///The following code was originally taken from http://www.yoursearchbuddy.com/create-tiff-image-multiple-images
    ///on Thursday May 9, 2013

    //Selecting the image encoder
    System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder enc = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag;
    ImageCodecInfo info = null;
    info = (from ie in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
            where ie.MimeType == "image/tiff"
            select ie).FirstOrDefault();
    EncoderParameters encoderparams = new EncoderParameters(2);
    encoderparams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
    encoderparams.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.ColorDepth, 4L);

    //Adding graphs of each project to TIFF image
    Bitmap tiffImage = null;
    Image img = null;
    foreach (DataRow row in dataOfManyProjects.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Project Code").Rows)
    {
        string projectCode = row["Project Code"].ToString();
        img = Image.FromFile("C:\\LMS\\Logs\\" + masterTitleWS + "ReportOf" + projectCode.Replace(" ", string.Empty) + ".jpg", false);
        if (row.Table.Rows.IndexOf(row) == 0)
        {
            //Saving the bitmap
            tiffImage = new Bitmap(250, 250, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);//This line was put which SEEMED to have solved the problem, according to a developer,but there is no prove that it ran correctly, and is still giving an exception
            tiffImage = (Bitmap)img;
            tiffImage.Save(fileName, info, encoderparams);
            encoderparams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
        }
        else
        {
            //Adding another image
            tiffImage.SaveAdd(img, encoderparams);
        }
        //img.Dispose();
    }
    //close file
    encoderparams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
    tiffImage.SaveAdd(encoderparams);
    tiffImage.Dispose();
}//Line:250
```

Comment: Does the location you are saving to exist? Does the application have the necessary permissions to save the file?

Comment: What Windows User is your service or server app running as?  You need to make sure it has permissions.  It is probably localhost.

Comment: I am having similar issues. Parameter is not valid.     at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams) while compressing the originally uploaded tiff file and then saving it back on the server. The code works great on the local machine.

Comment: Yes, the location exists.

Comment: The application is running as Administrator. The permissions issue was also raised by our network administrator, but it is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of struggle, the last parameter of line 222 was changed from `4L` to `24L`, and it worked! Thanks to my PM!

```
encoderparams.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.ColorDepth, 24L);
```

It seems that older versions of windows do not support some TIFF codecs. The older code was tested on Windows Server 2012 too, and it works.